# Microsoft bot framework emulator not working offline

Tags: emulation, botframework

Hi everyone  am trying to run the default project sample that comes with the MS bot framework template , when am connected to the internet the bot runs normally but when am offline the bot doesnt work and i got this error in the console :
**"POST getaddrinfo ENOENT localhost:3979"**
.does the emulator needs internet connection to work??? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Please report this issue on the Bot Framework Eumlator's GitHub repository here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/new

Comment: okay i will do that right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, currently you have to be online to use the emulator.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. :)